# If a Date exist return a calculated date

Tags: php, date, if-statement, view, return-value

I have the code below to add days to a date.

```
$date = '[[lbc_dates_lbc_date]]';
$date = date('d F y', strtotime('+28 days', strtotime($date)));
echo $date;
```

This works perfectly for cases where a date entry actually exists, however, it's displaying an odd date for cases where date entry doesn't exist yet (blank).

Can you amend the code to say if a date exists add days, otherwise leave blank?

Please see image attached (errors in red, correct view in green)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` will return `FALSE` when it can't parse the date. This is being treated as `0`, the epoch time, when you use it as the base time in the second call to `strtotime()`.

Check for that before trying to use the result.

```
$parsed = strtotime($date);
if ($parsed) {
    $date = date('d F y', strtotime('+28 days', $parsed));
} else {
    $date = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i did it as suggested (see below) $date = '[[lbc_dates_lbc_date|ifnull=ignore]]';
$parsed = strtotime($date);
if ($parsed) {
    $date = date('d F y', strtotime('+28 days', $parsed));
} else {
    $date = '';
}           Now all dates disapeared.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateTime object for storing and manipulating dates.

```
echo $date !== null ? (new DateTime($date))->add(new DateInterval('P28D'))->format('Your date format here') : '';
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Basically it uses a ternary operator to check if $date is null, if it's not, it creates a new DateTime object for the current date, adds 28 days and echoes it in a chosen format. If $date is null, it will just echo an empty string - ''.

Edit: The above is just an one-liner example, a good practice would be getting it into a function.